# Obtaining value of the Qdial as an integer and using that value in another python file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdial

I'm trying to work on displaying signals with different frequencies by varying a dial knob which is provided through the Qdial knob. The goal is to display a sine wave based on the knob setting. For example, setting number 1 represents 500kHz while setting 2 represents 1MHz and so on. How can I obtain the integer value "1" or "2" for settings 1 and 2 respectively? Thank you

Comment: You need to use signals and slots: connect the [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) signal to the function that updates the sine wave. See: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/signalsandslots.html and https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/

Answer (score 0):

Each time you change your dial, you want to connect it to a function that handles the new value. If you want to call a function in a different file, change self.your_dial.value() to your_file().your_function().

```
# Make below part of your class __init__
self.your_dial.valueChanged.connect(self.your_update_function)
self.your_update_function(self.your_dial.value())

    def your_update_function(self, value):
       print("The value of your_dial is: ", value)
       # Do things here
```

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop